# Access Denied Error Refreshing Child LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Building a kanban application in an LWC. Have code that executes on "drop" (made items draggable in the UI) to update the "case" that was dropped to a new status. This works fine the first time, but after trying to "move" the case again into a new status, I get the following error:

`Access denied: {"from":{"namespace":"c"},"to":{"namespace":"default"}}`

The error seems to be occurring when I'm trying to rerender the child component from the parent component.

These are snippets of the code:

parent.html

```
<template if:true={displaySdlcs}>
  <template for:each={displaySdlcs} if:true={caseMap} for:item="item">
    <lightning-layout-item key={item} dropzone="move" ondrop={drop_handler} ondragover={dragover_handler} class="custom-box slds-box slds-text-align_center"
                        size="2" flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" data-item={item}>
      <lightning-card class="lane-header" title={item}></lightning-card>
      <c-case-kanban-case-list sdlc={item} casemap={caseMap}></c-case-kanban-case-list>
    </lightning-layout-item>
  </template>
</template>
```

parent.js

```
@track caseMap
    @track displaySdlcs
    casesForDisplay
    sdlcs

    // TO DO: remove hardcoded id value
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012f4000000FCBIAA4', fieldApiName: SDLC_FIELD})
    sdlcResults(value) {
        this.sdlcs = value;
        const {err, data} = value;
        if(data) {
            this.displaySdlcs = [];
            data.values.forEach(sdlc => {
                if(!sdlcsToNotDisplay.includes(sdlc.value)) {
                    this.displaySdlcs.push(sdlc.value);
                }
            })
        }
    }
    
    // get cases and add them to the page accordingly per their sdlc in the form of a lightning card
    @wire(getCases)
    wiredCases(value) {
        this.casesForDisplay = value;
        const {data, error} = value;
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        if(data) {
            let tempCaseMap = {};
            data.forEach(c => {
                let sdlc;
                if(c.SDLC__c == null || c.SDLC__c === cabApprovalPending || c.SDLC__c === cabApprovedStatus) {
                    sdlc = 'Not Started';
                } else if(c.SDLC__c === bsrApprovedStatus) {
                    sdlc = 'Design';
                } else {
                    sdlc = c.SDLC__c;
                }
                if(sdlc in tempCaseMap) {
                    tempCaseMap[sdlc].push(c);
                } else {
                    tempCaseMap[sdlc] = [c];
                }
            })
            this.caseMap = tempCaseMap;
        }
    }

    dragover_handler(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    }
    
    drop_handler(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const caseId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
        const targetSdlc = ev.target.dataset.item;
        this.updateCaseSdlc(caseId, targetSdlc);
    }

    refreshCases = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            resolve(refreshApex(this.casesForDisplay));
        })
    }

    updateCaseSdlc(recordId, sdlc) {
        let caseRecord = {
            fields : {
                Id : recordId,
                SDLC__c : sdlc
            }
        };
        updateRecord(caseRecord)
        .then(() => {
            return this.refreshCases();
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.template.querySelectorAll("c-case-kanban-case-list").forEach(ele => {
                ele.refreshCasesForDisplay(this.caseMap);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Something happened' + error);
        })
    }
```

child.js

```
@api casemap;
    @api sdlc;
    @track cases;

    getCasesForDisplay = () => {
        this.cases = this.sdlc in this.casemap ? this.casemap[this.sdlc] : [];
    }

    @api refreshCasesForDisplay = (caseMap) => {
        console.log('Which sdlc is failing : ' + this.sdlc);
        this.casemap = caseMap;
        this.getCasesForDisplay();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.getCasesForDisplay();
    }

    dragstart_handler(ev) {
        // Add the target element's id to the data transfer object
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.dataset.item);
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
      }
```

child.html

```
<template for:each={cases} for:item="caseItem">
        <div id={caseItem.CaseNumber} key={caseItem.CaseNumber} draggable="true" ondragstart={dragstart_handler}
            data-item={caseItem.Id}>
            <lightning-card title={caseItem.CaseNumber}>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-body_small slds-text-align_left"><b>Subject:</b> {caseItem.Subject}</p>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-body_small slds-text-align_left"><b>Owner:</b> {caseItem.Owner.Name}</p>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-body_small slds-text-align_left"><b>Story Points:</b> {caseItem.LOE__c}</p>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-body_small slds-text-align_left"><b>SDLC:</b> {caseItem.SDLC__c}</p>
                <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small slds-text-body_small slds-text-align_center"><b><a href="">Description</a></b></p>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

change the refreshCasesForDisplay to function like this
`@api refreshCasesForDisplay(caseMap) { ....`

work for me

Comment: this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Hate to answer my own question, but was able to resolve by creating a lightning message channel and publishing / subscribing to changes from parent to child comps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that calling `refreshApex` on your `casesForDisplay` does not actually cause your wired function to run and is, therefore, your `caseMap` is not getting updated. I'd extract out the portion of your `wiredCases` method where you are constructing the `caseMap` into a separate method and call it after the `refreshApex` call as well.

Comment: Hey @suraj I'm not sure if thats correct though. The caseMap is getting updated and that  wired function is getting called. If I add debug statements I can see that it is getting called and casemap is getting updated. And this works the first time, its just the second time I try to "move" a card it fails. Unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: I see. Sounds like a miss on my part then. Just so that I'm clear, the error is on this line `this.template.querySelectorAll("c-case-kanban-case-list").forEach(ele => {
                ele.refreshCasesForDisplay(this.caseMap);
            });`?

Comment: No worries you are trying to help me out so I appreciate it lol. Correct, on the call to `refreshCasesForDisplay`. Again only the second time around though. Works without a hitch initially.